Update nodejs 16 to nodejs 20 for AWS lambda
I have limited knowledge of docker and aws
I am trying to update the nodejs from 16 to 20 but i am getting this error "error Package: 2:nodejs-20.12.2-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs) Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)"
My Dockerfile:
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.8.3

RUN yum update -y \
    && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
    && yum install -y nodejs which zip \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

The reason for this error is aws-cli is using amazonlinux:2 which only has glibs version 2.26
This same Dockerfile works for nodejs 16 version.
I tried various things like using amazonlinux:2023 as installer
Dockerfile:
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.15.42
FROM public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2023 as installer

RUN yum update -y \
    && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
    && yum install -y nodejs which zip \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

but this also fails stating Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'amazonlinux': Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/al2023/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240429/x86_64/mirror.list [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
I tried using amazon docker image too but that also didn't work
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20.2024.05.01.10

can someone please help me and share a Dockerfile that works in installing nodejs 20.
pipeline that run this dockerfile:
podTemplate(yaml: """
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: docker
      image: docker:20.10.24
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
""") {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        checkout(scm)

        def gitTag = env.GIT_COMMIT.take(8)

        final String dockerRegistry = # my org repository
        final String dockerBuildContext = "./jenkins/"

        final String buildImageName = "dcim-aws-node-build"
        final String buildImageDockerfilePath = "./jenkins/build-container.Dockerfile"
        final GString buildImageTag = "${dockerRegistry}/dcim/${buildImageName}:${gitTag}"

        container('docker') {
            stage('Create build container') {
                cre.dockerBuild(
                        dockerRegistry: dockerRegistry,
                        dockerImageTag: buildImageTag,
                        dockerfilePath: buildImageDockerfilePath,
                        dockerBuildContext: dockerBuildContext
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


You mention that public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20.2024.05.01.10 doesn't work. What was the problem there?
That will definitely give you Node 20.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]

For illustration I set BASH as the entrypoint and in the screenshot below you can see that Node 20 is indeed there!

If you specifically want to have the AWS CLI on the image then you might consider an alternative option, starting from a trimmed down Node image.
FROM node:20-slim

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -q -y awscli

Now you have both Node 20 and the AWS CLI.

Hi, so when i tried using FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20
my build pipeline was not able to push the docker image and gave me error 503 service unavailable
dockerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

Okay. But you were able to bulld the image? I understood the original question to be about a build problem.

so I need both aws cli and node 20
when i use this solution
FROM node:20-slim
RUN apt-get update -q && 
apt-get install -q -y awscli
my build pipeline through error
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
13:31:03  E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.

This is my original node 16 dockerfile that works perfectly, i need to update from node 16 to node 20 and need both aws cli and node 20
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.8.3
LABEL owner="DCIM-APIPlus-PO DCIM-APIPlus-PO@equinix.com" product="DCIM"
RUN yum update -y 
&& curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - 
&& yum install -y nodejs which zip 
&& yum clean all 
&& rm -rf /var/cache/yum
